# Telegram source code build failed

Tags: android, build, android-ndk, telegram

I have cloned into telegram source code repository from
https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram

When i want to Sync Project with Gradle Files,i got the error that was pasted in the following link:
https://justpaste.it/4qc1z

I think the problem is about Native Development Kit(NDK) but i have searched a lot and not found anything to solve the problem :(

Comment: @徐博俊 Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the solution.
at first we must download the Android NDK from SDK Tools, and then run ndk-build command on the root of the project.